# Refresh listview after SQLite update - Requery with spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a custom listview that displays my content extracted from a SQLite database. I also have the ability to  edit and update a single value of any given row. I have successfully implemented the update.

However, upon updating the row, the listview does NOT show the change. Should i change activity and go back the change has been implemented. From my understanding I need to requery the cursor to sync the data change.

My problem is that my listview contents can be changed dependent on the value of spinner (All, Catergory1, Catatergory2, etc...) therefore dependent on the spinner value, i would require a different cursor requery to be required followed by notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

*E.g.*

**Assuming I have a database of foods:**

I can edit and update a row value when all rows are displayed (NO category selected).
But also
I can edit and update a row value when category selected is fruit.

---

Therefore dependent on spinner category value I would have to run a particular cursor requery.

I have attempted to call my original class the runs through a series of 'if statements' to determine spinner value then select the correct cursor to be run however this requires the method to be static which isn't allowed when returning the spinner value.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that may help you, I used this to refresh a listview of cities depending on the state selected on a previous spinner

```
final stateAdapter stateadapter = new stateAdapter(this, StateList);
//customized adapter of state, it´s just an integer and a String

    StateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    StateSpinner.setAdapter(stateadapter);

    StateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            State state = (State) StateSpinner.getSelectedItem();
                            //Custom State Class, you may use your custom food class
            ArrayList<City> CitiesList = new ArrayList<City>();

            try {
                            //your new SQLite query to populate the CitiesList

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

            cityadapter = new cityAdapter(MyActivity.this, CitiesList);
                            //customized adapter for cities
            CitySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            CitySpinner.setAdapter(cityadapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this works for my problem. I can change my listview readout depending on the category chosen. I don't know how to refresh the listview after the database has changed for the given category.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to the requery and simply updated the array/adapter manually after the database was changed with the given value and then ran the notifyDataSetChanged() command to refresh the listview.